# Understanding BWD Acronym in genealogy diagrams?

Tags: united-kingdom, terminology

What does the acronym 'BWD' mean when it follows a name in a genealogy diagram?

I can't seem to find this explanation anywhere.

Comment: Hi Kerry & welcome to G&FH:SE. On pedigree charts it can stand for b(orn), w(here), d(ied). Do you have an example where the acronym is used?

Answer (score 1):

On some pedigree charts it can stand for b(orn), w(here born), d(ied):

[image: Pedigree chart]

The M on the record numbered 50 stands for m(arried).

The idea is that you record the dates next to the b, m, and d, and the place where it happened next to the w.

---

The columns further to the left of the chart have more space allowing you to record the location for all the events:

[image: Pedigree chart 2]